# Convert multer file to string

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm using multer to read in multi-part form data. However, I don't actually want to upload it. I want to put its contents into a string. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-file fields are not stored on disk when you use multer's `DiskStorage` (the default storage type).

However, if you want files to be stored in memory too, then you need to use multer's [MemoryStorage](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#memorystorage) which will store files as Buffers, which you can then convert to string if you like:

```
var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// ...

app.post('/profile', upload.single('aboutme'), function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.file.buffer);
});
```